# AnjularJS - Naming Conventions for Nested Directives

Tags: angularjs, naming-conventions

I am using several AngularJS directives nested in each other. Works great. However I would like to have a naming convention for nested directives that indicates that they are nested and what they can be nested in, so that a developer would not think to nest a directive of mine in the wrong place.

AngularJS has some good notes on their conventions here.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

But nothing about nesting directives though.

I use '-' to separate words on the html side and camel case to separate words on the JS side, but what about separating modules like so.

in HTML

```
<dir.top-module.sub-module></dir.top-module.sub-module>
```

in JS

```
dir.topModule.subModule
```

This seems to work, but I was just wondering if there was a "proper way". Thanks.

Comment: Normally `parent-child` like `accordion` and `accordion-group`. But I also saw `tab` and `panel` so, I don't see a common convention.

Comment: personally would not use `dot` notation in markup. If you need to use same directive as `class` would make some strange classNames and thus have css selector problems

Comment: @charlietfl Good point, that's why I am asking. What should I use?

Comment: what's wrong with `-` and `_` separators?

Comment: @charlietfl Nothing, that's what I am asking. Which one do you use to separate words and which one for separating modules?